# Plot interpolate data in basemap (pyplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot over a map the interpolated data of temperature.

```
a = [(41.42,2.11,24),(40.40,2.2,15),(41.9,3,6),(40.3,4.4,10),(42.3,4.1,15),(39.2,3.5,16)]
```

The structure is: `a = [(lat,lon,data),(lat,lon,data)...(lat,lon,data)]`

I try this code:

```
lats = [ x[0] for x in a ]
lons = [ x[1] for x in a ]
data = [ x[2] for x in a ]

lat_min = min(lats)
lat_max = max(lats)
lon_min = min(lons)
lon_max = max(lons)
data_min = min(data)
data_max = max(data)

spatial_resolution = 0.5
fig = plt.figure()

x = np.array(lons)
y = np.array(lats)
z = np.array(data)

xinum = (lon_max - lon_min) / spatial_resolution
yinum = (lat_max - lat_min) / spatial_resolution
xi = np.linspace(lon_min, lon_max + spatial_resolution, xinum)       
yi = np.linspace(lat_min, lat_max + spatial_resolution, yinum)       
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)

m = Basemap(.....)

lat, lon = m.makegrid(zi.shape[1], zi.shape[0])
x,y = m(lat, lon)
m.contourf(x, y, zi)

plt.show()
```

When I test the code I receive more future Warnings:

```
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
```

And this error:

```
ValueError: Unknown interpolation method array([[ 2.11,  3.04,  3.97,  4.9 ],
   [ 2.11,  3.04,  3.97,  4.9 ],
   [ 2.11,  3.04,  3.97,  4.9 ],
   [ 2.11,  3.04,  3.97,  4.9 ],
   [ 2.11,  3.04,  3.97,  4.9 ],
   [ 2.11,  3.04,  3.97,  4.9 ]]) for 1 dimensional data
```

What happens? How can I do?

Thanks!

Marc